# Pooling frequencies after multiple imputation in SAS

Tags: sas, imputation, pooling

I have imputed data using multiple imputation using PROC MI in SAS, generating n imputed datasets. Now, I would like to report a baseline table with imputed values. However, I cannot find the right SAS code to do so. I've used PROC FREQ using a BY _ imputation _ statement, to get n baseline tables. I want to combine these n tables into just one, with pooled frequencies for every category of the covariates.

Apparently this is fairly easy in SPSS but not in SAS. I found some topics suggesting PROC MIANALYZE, which might be a solution, but the examples I found only considered estimates in for example regression models. Does someone have a suggestion on how to combine the frequencies from n imputed datasets into one pooled baseline table?

Many thanks!

Comment: Show the code you are submitting and example of desired result table.  Show sample data that reproduces the problem.  You might want to look into using `Proc REPORT` and `columns category_var _imputation_ ...; define _imputation_ / group; define category_var / group;`

Answer (score 0):

I find a possible way for you from SAS Forum: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Statistical-Procedures/proc-freq-with-multiple-imputation/td-p/671680

As it says, `proc mianalysze` require point estimation and standard error of n times imputations, but `proc freq` doesn't compute it. So you need to use `proc surveyfreq`. Then, just programing like ususal:

```
proc minanlysze data = MyData;
  modeleffcts Percent;
  stdder stddev;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found some PROC SURVEYFREQ code earlier on in my search but somehow the code did not work then. But I tried the code again and now it works!  
 
I realized that another solution could be applied as well: the weighted frequencies of PROC MIANALYZE are the same as when performing PROC UNIVARIATE and dividing the frequency counts by the n imputations.